# Transferring Excel via PHP header()

Tags: php, excel, header

An Excel file is stored in a database (hexvalues of former binary data). I need to read it and make it available for download.

Here's the code...

```
$out = hex2bin($out); // the stuff from the database


header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");  
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
die($out);
```

Actually I receive stuff... and it looks like the original file with a slight difference.
When using a hex-editor, it shows

```
    ÐÏà¡±á
```

instead of

```
ÐÏà¡±á
```

(looks like an additional tab). So Excel isn't able to show the sheet but the raw data.

That's not from the data in `$out`; the conversion bin2hex (during import in database) and hex2bin (export from database) works without problems. If I write `$out` to a file via fopen / fwrite, it's exactly the original Excel file (which I can open normally).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is a very localized question, however I think it could be to do with some echoing out of blank space before the die();

Comment: Why you are using die? die is like exit and should be an error code or something. Why not echo $out; exit();

Comment: well, actually both versions don't show a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you don't have this extra tab character before the opening `<?php` tag or after the closing one `?>`. Actually, it is good practice to omit the closing tag exactly for this reason.

Comment: Still the same - but a strange thing: exporting a pdf is possible without problems.